# Basic Calculus Question Using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

How does one use the Mean Value Theorem to show:

$\frac{1 - e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} \leq min(1, \frac{1}{\lambda})$

Comment: Recognize that $(1-e^{-\lambda})/\lambda=-(e^{-\lambda}-e^0)/(\lambda-0)$ i.e. the average rate of change of $e^x$ on $[0,\lambda]$. What does the mean value theorem tell you, again?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question.